# Add second item to module in angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add ngStorage to a module that already has functionality.  I am really new to angular so forgive me for my incorrect usage of terms. I thought I had ngStorage added right into the module but the code breaks when I add it.

Origional code:

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('mobsocial.climbs', [
 'ionic',
])
```

Added with ngStogare:

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('mobsocial.climbs', ['ngStorage',
 'ionic',
])
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without the error message

Comment: You have to call it with the `<link>` tag - just like Angular. Also, you can use your JS packing system to call it

Comment: How does the link tag work Im super new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'use strict';
angular.module('mobsocial.climbs', ['ngStorage','ionic'])
```

you are using extra comma in your code. Also make sure you have included ng-storage library file in index

Comment: its saying ngStogage.min not found but the file was installed in the app